# Pandas pivoting string columns impossible?

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

I am looking to pivot the feature column into column headers.

here is the df

[image]

for instance neither of the below work. I've tried multiple variations to no avail.

```
df.groupby(['feature', 'year'])['value'].unstack(fill_value=0)

df.pivot_table(index='year', columns='feature', values='value')
```

The end goal would look like this.

[image]

Comment: kindly post data, not images/pics. use this as a guide on how to post minimum viable reproducible example : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: can you provide your df as code as opposed to an excel screengrab?

Comment: Use `pivot` instead of `pivot_table`. `pivot` is a simple reshaping of the data, which is what you want here. `pivot_table` is more when you want to aggregate (or reshape with MultiIndices). You'd need to use `aggfunc='first'` with `pivot_table` to deal with strings as the default assumption is you aggregate with `mean` with `pivot_table`.

Answer (score 2):

You are going from a long layout to wide layout.  See the sample below.

```
import pandas as pd

df_long = pd.DataFrame({
        "student":
            ["Andy", "Bernie", "Cindy", "Deb",
             "Andy", "Bernie", "Cindy", "Deb",
             "Andy", "Bernie", "Cindy", "Deb"],
        "school":
            ["Z", "Y", "Z", "Y",
             "Z", "Y", "Z", "Y",
             "Z", "Y", "Z", "Y"],
        "class":
            ["english", "english", "english", "english",
             "math", "math", "math", "math",
             "physics", "physics", "physics", "physics"],
        "grade":
            [10, 100, 1000, 10000,
             20, 200, 2000, 20000,
             30, 300, 3000, 30000]
})
df_long
```

[image]

```
df_long.pivot_table(index=["student", "school"], 
                    columns='class', 
                    values='grade').reset_index()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

@ALollz tipped me off on this one. I should have been using pivot and not pivot_table.

```
df = pd.pivot(df, values='value', columns='feature', index='year')
```